# Android ListView on click listener not working

Tags: java, android, listview

I have implemented a search bar which fills a list of search results every time a search token is inserted. My XML goes like this:

```
<android.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/my_searchView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:queryHint="Search Here" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Once the token is inserted, an api is invoked and the results are stored in a list called resultUsers. I am populating the ListView like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ListView list = findViewById(R.id.my_listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userNames);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        getSelectedUserDetails(list);
    }
});
```

getSelectedUserDetails() function is called to prepare the listener for the item click:

```
public void getSelectedUserDetails(ListView list){
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selection = (String) list.getItemAtPosition(i);
            User selectedUser = new User();
            for(int j = 0; j < resultUsers.size(); j++) {
                if(selection.equals(resultUsers.get(j).getName())){
                    selectedUser = resultUsers.get(j);
                    System.out.print(selectedUser.getId());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectedUser.getId().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

2 unexpected results occur:

1. The system output appears not when i click the item on the list but after clicking the item and reinserting a search token
2. The Toast does not appear at all

Is this a bug or have i got it wrong all together and there's a different approach for search results lists?

Comment: `Toast` isn't showing, because you are using wrong `Context`. use `view.getContext()` or `MyActivity.this` (GUI's context) instead of base

Comment: use interface methodology that will work fine rather than this